# NSStackView does not layout views properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstackview

I've just started experimenting with `NSStackView`, and I'm having a very interesting problem which I can't solve. I've scoured the auto layout guides on Apple's website as well as the `NSStackView` documentation, and can't seem to find anything.

My problem is that I have two identical `NSScrollView` objects (each with an embedded `NSTextView`) which are loaded from nib files. When I add these views to my stack view, the one that is added first takes up 100% of the available space, and the second collapses completely down to the bottom with a height of 2 pixels while taking up all available horizontal space. In effect, this looks like the first view is the only one in the window. Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: A screenshot of the problematic window]

It's nearly impossible to see in this example because of the background color, but the scroll view ends a couple pixels above the bottom of the window. Here's a better view from the view hierarchy inspector, where I have this 2 pixel high view selected ([click here to view larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJeG5.png)):

[image: The Xcode view hierarchy inspector]

Here's the relevant setup code:

```
// Load the stack view
self.inputViewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Document_TextInputView" bundle:nil];
self.textView = (NSTextView *)[[(NSScrollView *)self.inputViewController.view contentView] documentView];

self.outputViewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Document_TextOutputView" bundle:nil];
self.outputView = (NSTextView *)[[(NSScrollView *)self.outputViewController.view contentView] documentView];

// Add all views into the stack view
[self.stackView addView:self.inputViewController.view inGravity:NSStackViewGravityTop];
[self.stackView addView:self.outputViewController.view inGravity:NSStackViewGravityBottom];
self.stackView.orientation = NSUserInterfaceLayoutOrientationVertical;

// Load the text into the window.
[self.textView setString:self.cachedText];
[self.outputView setString:@"=== PROGRAM OUTPUT ===\n"];
[self.codeActionSegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegment:1];
```

From what I understand, the intrinsic content size *should* prohibit the view from getting shrunk this small. I'm not too familiar with `NSStackView`, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use `NSStackViewGravityTop` for both subviews?

Comment: @Astoria Yes, and that doesn't do anything visibly different than what I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I've found the solution to my own problem and I am posting it so everyone who searches for this and finds the question will have the answer.

The issue is that `NSScrollView` does not have an intrinsic content size, which prohibits the `NSStackView` which knowing what height it ought to be, hence the second `NSScrollView` was being collapsed. The constraints created by default in Xcode give the `NSScrollView`'s relation to other elements, but this information does not tell the stack view anything about what its height should be.

The solution is to add a height constraint to the `NSScrollView` (programmatically or in Interface Builder) so that `NSStackView` can lay out the views properly. Then, it all just magically works.